# Recurrence logic app get azure alert search results url

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

[image]I have a logic app with an HTTP Trigger is triggered whenever an alert rule is met. On this event, the entire alert response is sent to the logic app where I can parse the JSON to extract the information I need such as the Search Results URL.

However, I want to create a Recurrence Logic App that queries App Insights logs. If the condition is met, I want to send an email. I tried this but a limitation of this is that I am not able to include the Search Results URL in the email. Is there a way to get the Search Results URL or form one in case of a Recurrence Logic App?

I have attached my Recurrence Logic App design. As of now; it queries the App Insight logs, and it sends an email alert by combining the output rows. However, it does not include the link to the search results. Is it possible to include a link to the search results in this scenario?

Comment: Please provide the codes for this problem and please read more on how to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help if we don't have any code to work with.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, I think it's impossible for us to get the `LinkToSearchResults` field in logic app. When you use HTTP trigger in logic app, the alert send the entire alert request to your logic app, so it contains the `LinkToSearchResults` field. But when we use "Run analytics query" action, it just get the result searched by the query. So it doesn't contain the `LinkToSearchResults` field. Apart from this, we can not find any other connectors/actions for us to get the `LinkToSearchResults`.

As a workaround, I think you can just go to your application insights logs page on azure portal and copy the link, put it in the email in your logic app and also include the query command in the email. Then the user who receive the email can use the link and the query command to go to the page and run the query, same effect as open the page by "LinkToSearchResults" directly.

By the way, you can also create a feedback ticket on this [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to suggest azure team to add this feature.